# Early stopping based on average val_loss of last ten epoches and with some n partiences

Tags: keras, tensorflow, loss-function, multi-output, early-stopping

I am training a DNN with CNN in Keras. Though, I can write an EarlyStopping criteria based on val_loss but due to minor oscillations in the val_loss, I want to monitor the average validation loss over last n epoches and with n patience.

How can I do this in Keras?

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a custom callback inheriting the [tf.keras.callbacks.Callback()](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/base_callback/) class. You would need to override the `on_epoch_end()` method with your custom logic.